# Foundry remapping error VS Code: foundry config error: stream did not contain valid UTF-8 in Remapping Provider

Tags: rust, foundry, framework

Im trying to use Foundry with VS Code.

-I removed both the default contract and default test and replaced them with my own .sol file

-I copied over my remapping file into the root directory using the "forge remappings > remappings.txt" command.

Then when I went to install a dependency using "forge install owner/directory"

I received the error:
foundry config error: stream did not contain valid UTF-8 in Remapping Provider

Anyone have any thoughts? I think it obviously may have something to do with changing the location of my remappings.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and as a workaround I did:

- Create file remappings.txt in vs code
- Run forge remappings (will display the remappings)
- Copy the console displayed remappings into the remappings.txt file above created.

Hope it helps

Comment: A similar workaround worked for me. Delete `remappings.txt` is if it has already been created. Create an empty `remappings.txt` in vs code. Follow the next steps given above. Type in any new mappings in the file. Then the error should be gone.